# SSIS script task errors out when executing from SQL Server Agent Job . System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have SQL Server 2019 installed on a Windows 2019 Virtual machine. Microsoft Visual studio Professional 2012 is installed on that server.

- I have bunch of SSIS packages in a project, some of those have script task written in C# 2012 and all those run fine from Visual Studio.
- Any package which has a script task fails when ran from SQL Server Agent job with following errors.

> Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx'
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.b__31_0()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSTADenaliScriptProject(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
> End Error
> Error: 2021-01-21 20:52:01.92
> Code: 0x00000003
> Source: Create Voucher in ERP
> Description: The Script Task is corrupted.
> End Error
> Error: 2021-01-21 20:52:01.92
> Code: 0xC0024107
> Source: Create Voucher in ERP
> Description: There were errors during task validation.
> End Error
> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
> Started:  8:52:01 PM
> Finished: 8:52:01 PM
> Elapsed:  0.5 seconds

Some of the thread talked about changing the project property Run64bitruntime to False , didn't work.

Some threads talked about reinstalling SQL Server and Visual Studio but I really don't want to do that as many of those talks about a lot of other errors pops up after reinstalling.

Please suggest what can be done to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: 1) Are you sure VS 2012 is completely compatible with SQL Server 2019? 2) How do you deploy your packages, and to where?

Comment: @RogerWolf , you are right. I installed the VS2019 Professional , Open a new project in 2019 , added all my 2012 packages in the new project which upgraded all of them. I did see warnings about script task needs to be migrated but all of them started working as expected. Sql jobs started executing all the packages with/without script tasks.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Translated - DLL of Version 15.0.0.0 of "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications" can not be found.

The message is handy, but it doesn't tell you if the 64/32 bit dll is missing.   Some folks take a guess to switch between 32/64 mode and get lucky.

Check your Programs and Featured to confirm
"Microsoft Visual Studion Tools for Application 2017" is installed.

Version 14.0 = VSTA 2015

Version 15.0 = VSTA 2017

Version 16.0 = VSTA 2019

Past Version 12, the vsta installer should install dlls for both 32/64 bit support.

Comment: I see Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Application 2012 was installed , not 2017. So, if 2017 version was installed, these 2012 packages would have worked with 2019 sql server...? Just curios.

Comment: It should get you past this specific error.   Haven't tried it directly.  Generally we get less headache when we [match SSDT to SQL Server Version](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/) .   Starting with a more recent version of Visual Studio and target a (at or lower) version of SQL Server in the project properties.   But those missing dll issues still show up once in a while if you access a library VS can get to but is not in the global assembly cache of the Server.